# matriz de 5x5 que solo imprima las palabras que empiezen con vocales

Tags: c

Tengo una matriz de 5x5 y quiero que solo imprima las palabras que empiezen con vocales.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char texto[5][5][40];
    int inicial[5][5], vocales = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            printf("ingresa la palabra [%i] para ver con que vocales empieza:", vocales);
            gets(texto[i][j]);
            inicial[i][j] = strlen(texto[i][j]);
            vocales++;
        }
    }
    if (inicial == 'a' || inicial == 'e' || inicial == 'i' || inicial == 'o' || inicial == 'u') {
    }
    vocales = 1;
    for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < 5; b++) {
            printf("\nLa palabra [%i] es %s empieza con las siguientes vocales[%d]", vocales, texto[a][b], inicial[a][b]);
            vocales++;
        }
    }
}
```

Así es como lo hice pero no sale como tiene que ser.

Comment: Hola gustavo XD . ¿Que problemas te sale en tu codigo? y ¿Como es tu codigo?. Te sugiero que coloques tu intento en la pregunta. Aprovechando que eres nuevo te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganar tu 1° medalla :), Tambien te invito a leer [¿Como hacer una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [¿Que debo evitar preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Nadie debería usar `gets`. En este video se explica por qué: https://youtu.be/qpyRz5lkRjE

Answer (score 1):

`inicial` es una matriz dónde guardas la longitud de cada cadena:

```
inicial[i][j] = strlen(texto[i][j]);
```

Pero pretendes comparar la matriz con un caracter:

```
inicial == 'a' || inicial == 'e' || inicial == 'i' || inicial == 'o' || inicial == 'u'
```

Los tipos no coinciden. No puedes hacer eso.

Lo que si puedes hacer es, crear una funcion que te ayude a saber si un carácter es una vocal:

```
int esVocal(char c){
    // Convertir caracter a minúscula.
    c = tolower(c);
    return c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u';
}
```

La función [`tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower) se encuentra en la cabecera `ctype.h`.

Y ahora en el segundo for, solo imprimir las palabras si su primera letra es una vocal. Nota que `texto[a][b][0]` corresponde a la primera letra de la palabra.

```
for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
    for (int b = 0; b < 5; b++) {
        if (esVocal(texto[a][b][0])) {

            printf("\nLa palabra [%i] es %s empieza con las siguientes vocales[%d]", vocales, texto[a][b], inicial[a][b]);
        }
    }
}
```